# Hibernate Enable PostLoad Event

Tags: java, hibernate, events, loading

I'm currently trying to use the `@PostLoad` Annotation for some processing after my model has been loaded from the database. But at the moment it looks like that my method won't get triggered. I don't use the `EntityManager` so I'm looking for a way to enable this event bahavior.

My configuration looks like this:

```xml
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.tinyInt1isBit">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testing</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <!-- OUTPUT STUFF -->
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql">false</property>
        <!-- SESSION CONTEXT -->
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <!-- CONNECTION POOL hikariCP -->
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.maximumPoolSize">25</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.idleTimeout">30000</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testing</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.user">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.password"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.cachePrepStmts">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.prepStmtCacheSize">250</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit">2048</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.useServerPrepStmts">true</property>
        <!-- Include the mapping entries -->
        <mapping class="at.adtime.core.v1.model.User"/>
        <mapping class="at.adtime.core.v1.model.Test"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Update:

I have a method called `afterUserLoad` which looks like this:

```
@PostLoad
public void afterUserLoad() {
    ArrayList<String> computedIds = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Test test : this.Test) {
        computedIds.add(test.getId());
    }
    this.setTestIds(computedIds);
}
```

It should load the `Test` `List` and put only the `ids` in an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Where have you marked this `@PostLoad`?

Comment: I have tried using the Annotation in the User class with the method `afterUserLoad`, than i tried using `<listener class="org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPostLoadEventListener"/>` in the hibernate config - doesn't work as expected. any ideas?

Comment: That should work when you load an instance of `Test` class. Are you doing it? Have you prepared a unit test or something else to debug this?

Comment: I tried loading it from the database but when i try to access the testIds ArrayList which should be set throw this PostLoad method it is null. I think i need to say that i'm not using EntityManager - i'm using a SessionFactory and doing the rest myself - do i need to enable it somewhere in the configuration?

Comment: So you're using a jpa annotation but you're not using jpa to retrieve your entity (and thus fire the `@PostLoad` event). Well, I guess you had too much expectations on non-jpa firing a jpa event.

Comment: That's sad. I thought using hibernate + the sessionFactory would allow me to use these PostLoad Events - thanks anyway.

Comment: @DominikAngerer, did you solve this issue? I am in the same scenario.

Comment: @AngelAvila did you solve this? I'm using Hibernate + Spring and I just can't get this to execute. I'm doing all the initialization manually, but I can't keep on doing it all the way through the project I'm currently working on

Comment: @AngelAvila I sadly wasn't able to get this directly running with a `PostLoad` event. In this API Project I was able to add my `PostLoad` functionallity as Pre Delivery Task - right before the serialization into JSON.

Comment: Did you found a Solution anyway? Also @JeffersonTavares is still looking for a way to do this.

Comment: Looks like this is an issue with HibernateSessionFactory. I didn't manage to get it working, but that's what I've found out so far.

Comment: @JeffersonTavares I hope that my answer help you. Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According with my research, `@PostLoad`, `@PrePersist` and other kinds of these  JPA annotations do not work for Hibernate, instead of them, we can use Interceptors. I am using Hibernate-JPA and Spring with xml based configuration. With Spring I get a `SessionFactory` object, when i set the properties for this object I inject a `MyInterceptor` instance that extends `EmptyInterceptor` class, then you can overide several methods like `postLoad`, `onSave`, etc. When you implement this code, the overrided methods are executed according the life cycle of the operation. I have not tested the `postLoad` method because `onSave` method worked for me.

**Update**

Spring Java based configuration @JeffersonTavares:

Spring configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringConfig {

    @Bean
    public BasicDataSource basicDataSource(){ // org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource Object
        BasicDataSource basicDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        basicDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        basicDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:sqlserver://172.125.25.7:1433;databaseName=LIST_FIRMAS;selectMethod=direct;");
        basicDataSource.setUsername("user");
        basicDataSource.setPassword("password");
        return basicDataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public MyInterceptor myInterceptor(){  // Your interceptor
        return new MyInterceptor();
    }

    @Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() throws IOException{
        LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

        localSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(basicDataSource()); // DataSource

        localSessionFactoryBean.setAnnotatedClasses(
                com.isapeg.timbrado.model.SalMinimo.class,
                com.isapeg.timbrado.model.DeduccionCnom12.class,
                com.isapeg.timbrado.model.PercepcionCnom12.class); // JPA entity classes ....

        localSessionFactoryBean.setEntityInterceptor(myInterceptor()); // Setting your Interceptor

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "thread");
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "false");
        localSessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(properties);  // Setting Hibernate Properties

        localSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();  // Session Factory initialization

        return localSessionFactoryBean.getObject();  // Returning of SessionFactory Object
    }

    // other beans ....
}
```

Something to test session factory object:

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringConfig.class);
SessionFactory sessionFactory = (SessionFactory) ctx.getBean("sessionFactory");
if (sessionFactory == null) {
    System.out.println("SessionFactory obj is null");
} else {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    System.out.println("Session obj: " + session);
    System.out.println("isOpen: " + session.isOpen() + "  isConnected: " + session.isConnected());
    session.close();
}
```

**Update 2**

How to implement an Interceptor [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html).

Comment: I'm currently learning spring, but I'm using java based configuration. Any ideas on how to get this working? I know how to create an Interceptor, but I have no clue on how to "inject" it on spring.

Answer (score 3):

@PostLoad handling **is implemented at least since 5.2.17** version in Hibernate.